# Cron output to nothing

Tags: cron, wget

I've noticed that my cron outputs are creating index.html files on my server.  The command I'm using is `wget http://www.example.com 2>&1`.  I've also tried including `--reject "index.html*"`

How can I prevent the output from creating `index.html` files?

```
--2013-07-21 16:03:01--  http://www.examplel.com
Resolving example.com... 192.0.43.10
Connecting to www.example.com|192.0.43.10|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 0 [text/html]
Saving to: `index.html.9'

     0K                                                        0.00 =0s

2013-07-21 16:03:03 (0.00 B/s) - `index.html.9' saved [0/0]
```

Comment: Which user is the cronjob running on behalf of? You? `www`? Someone else?

Comment: Presumably `http://www.my-url.com` resolves to `http://www.my-url.com/index.html`. Why are you running `wget` if not to create `index.html`? Where do you expect the output to be written?

Comment: @KeithThompson The site is written in CodeIgniter, so I'm only using `wget` to trigger items on my `cron` controller.

Comment: I've edited your question to change "my-url.com" to "example.com". I've also changed the IP address. "my-url.com" is a real site; "example.com" is a reserved domain name intended to be used in examples. Feel free to revert my edit or re-edit the question if this changes the meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, the whole point of running `wget` is to create an output file. A URL like `http://www.example.com` typically resolves to `http://www.example.com/index.html`, so by creating `index.html`, the `wget` command is just doing its job.

If you want to run `wget` and *discard* the downloaded file, you can use:

```
wget -q -O /dev/null http://www.example.com
```

The `-o /dev/null` discards log messages; `-O /dev/null` discards the downloaded file.

If you want to be sure that anything `wget` writes to stdout or stderr is discarded:

```
wget -q -O /dev/null http://www.example.com >/dev/null 2>&1
```

In a comment, you say that you're using the `wget` command to "trigger items on your `cron` controller" using CodeIgniter. I'm not familiar with CodeIgniter, but downloading and discarding an HTML file seems inefficient. I suspect (and hope) that there's a cleaner way to do whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: CodeIgniter is a PHP framework that isn't the most friendly with cron commands.  Thanks for the help.